# cakephp - what is the validation rule for email

Tags: javascript, php, validation, cakephp

I have a form in my cakephp app which requires an email address. I'm using some custom javascript validation to make sure the email address is valid and I want to mimic however cakephp decides if an email address is valid so I know it'll save ok when the form actually submits.

So at the minute I'm only checking if there's an @ symbol. What else does cakephp do to check an email address is valid?

Answer (score 2):

Please read the documentation
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#Validation::email

And take a look at the source code. All the answers are right there.

Answer (score 2):

```
class User extends AppModel {
    public $validate = array(
        'email' => array(
            array(
                'rule' => array('email'),
                'message' => 'Please enter a valid email address',
            ),
        ),
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your Model,put this

```
public $validate = array(
             //.... other validation here
        'email'=>array(
            'Valid email'=>array(
                'rule'=>array('email'),
                'message'=>'Please enter a valid email address'
            ),));
```

It'll automatically validate it when you submit (save)